# Android: Switch controls are not correctly displayed on Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with Switch controls. They are not correctly displayed on some devices. Please see the following image:

[image]

And it's code:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <Switch                        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full screen"
        android:id="@+id/optionFullscreen"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="onOptionBtClick"
        android:checked="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could you please help, is it possible to make this ON/OFF trigger max width not take more than about 40%?

Comment: pl share your full xml and not just switch part

Comment: I've edited my post. Please see. This problem is only on Samsung devices. The switch is very wide. How to reduce its width?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution. Very strange (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with long texts. I solved it by setting my own text:

```
android:textOn="I"
android:textOff="O"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `android:switchMinWidth="50dp"` attribute on your switch widget. that will make it smaller